# jqGrid apply colspan to column header

Tags: jqgrid, html-table

Does jqGrid supports colspan on column header? I find this grid control useful because it has a lot of features and importantly plenty of documentation.

And how about the stylesheet? how to change the look and feel of the grid?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can change the look-and-feel by downloading themes from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ - the site even allows you to customize them. Then just drop the theme into your page(s).

What do you mean by colspan? If you mean having a header span multiple columns then no, I do not believe it supports that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding colspan,

its still not supported in jqGrid officially, here is the workaround,

jQgrid: multiple column row headers

Working example posted by @[Oleg](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeaders3.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Header grouping is supported since version 4.2.0. See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agroupingheadar)

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for that and I didn't find any answer.

I've managed to get 2 rows of headers like so:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|  Col Group 1 (3 Columns)     | Col Group 2 (2 Columns) |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  Col 1  |  Col 2  |   Col 3  |    Col 4    |   Col 5   |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Using a `gridComplete` event to add a row `.before` the row defined on the

```
gridComplete: function (){
    if (!$('#super_header').length) {
        $('#jqgridContainer tr.ui-jqgrid-labels').before('<tr id="super_header" class="bigHeader ui-jqgrid-labels"><th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" colspan="3">Col Group 1</th><th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" colspan="2">Col Group 2</th></tr>');
    }
},
```

I hope this helps.

**Edited:**
After testing it more, I've realized **it doesn't work very well** and it can mess the width of the second row of headers ( `Col 1` to `Col 5` )

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: false, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'col2', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'Col Group 1 (3 Columns) '},
    {startColumnName: 'col4', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: ' Col Group 2 (2 Columns) '}
  ]
});
```

to set column parameters.

To remove the colum headers you can use,

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('destroyGroupHeader'); Or
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('destroyGroupHeader', false);
```